# Update a ManyToOne relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an entity I want to update its ManyToOne relation. I have FicheSynthese ManyToOne Demandeur relation. When I want to edit a FicheSynthese object, I send forms of FicheSynthese and Demandeur filled with informations from the database.

A user can decide to change the Demandeur information to a brand new one. I deal with this case with an AJAX call, if the Demandeur doesn't exist I set the ID field of Demandeur form to -1. In this specific case, I'd like to create a Demandeur object (and in database) and update the FicheSynthese<->Demandeur relation.

Small remarks Demandeur is an abstract class with inheritance in 4 different classes. On edition, a user can change the type of Demandeur or a Demandeur of the same type but still a new one.

I've read several times that on update I have to update the entity that owned the relation. If I understood correctly it is FicheSynthese here.

Some code with my entities :

```
Demandeur.php
    /**
     *@var Collection|FicheSynthese[]
     *
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FicheSynthese", mappedBy="demandeur", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     *
     */
    private $ficheSynthese;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ficheSynthese = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|FicheSynthese[]
     */
    public function getFicheSynthese(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ficheSynthese;
    }

    public function addFicheSynthese(FicheSynthese $ficheSynthese): self
    {
        if (!$this->ficheSynthese->contains($ficheSynthese)) {
            $this->ficheSynthese[] = $ficheSynthese;
            $ficheSynthese->setDemandeur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFicheSynthese(FicheSynthese $ficheSynthese): self
    {
        if ($this->ficheSynthese->contains($ficheSynthese)) {
            $this->ficheSynthese->removeElement($ficheSynthese);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($ficheSynthese->getDemandeur() === $this) {
                $ficheSynthese->setDemandeur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


FicheSynthese.php
    /**
     * @var \Demandeur
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Demandeur", 
     * inversedBy="ficheSynthese", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idDemandeur",      referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $demandeur;    

    public function getDemandeur(): ?Demandeur
    {
        return $this->demandeur;
    }

    public function setDemandeur(?Demandeur $demandeur): self
    {
        $this->demandeur = $demandeur;

        return $this;
    }
```

Now my controller (bit messy):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('fichesynthese');
//My Demandeur form
$formsDem[$typeDem]->handleRequest($request);
//I get my Demandeur entity filled
$dem = $formsDem[$typeDem]->getData();
//I get the ID
$id = $dem->getId();
//If ID is -1 that means that my Demandeur doesn't exist
if ($id == -1) {
    //I detach the old Demandeur entity, I don't want to remove it
    $em->detach($dem);
    //I create a new Demandeur entity (which should be the same as $dem)
    $newDem = $formsDem[$typeDem]->getData();
    //I attach the $newDem to my FicheSynthese that I'm currently editing
    $fs->setDemandeur($newDem);
    $em->flush();
}
```

I'm starting with Symfony so my understanding of Doctrine and Entities etc... is that I don't have to persist $fs since it is an edition form. If I dump the $fs I takes into account the change of Demandeur. The problem is in database, It creates the new Demandeur but does not change the foreign key in FicheSynthese table. Also, it doesn't update the relation in Demandeur entity.

My guess is that with the -1 ID, it can't update the relation but then I don't understand how it can work on full creation (of FicheSynthese and Demandeur).

More informations, in my controller I have a form for FicheSynthese and an array forms for Demandeur with all types of forms. With inheritance I didn't find how to embed it in FicheSynthese form.

What did I not understand in Doctrine and update ? Thanks.

Edit : add getters/setters.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? If you don't see the error message, e.g. because it is an AJAX-Request, please take a look at the logs (probably in `var/log/dev.log`).

Comment: I don't have any error and the AJAX request is doing the right job. My issue is that at the flush() =, my foreign key in the FicheSynthese table is not update with the right new Demandeur which is created in the database. It is like the setDemandeur() method is not taken into account at the flush.

Comment: can you show your getters and setters implementations?

Comment: does `$em` variable holds `FicheSynthese` repository?

Comment: I've added the getters and setters. $em is my entity manager for my database including FicheSynthese and Demandeur tables. What about repository ? Did I miss something ?